How can I get a URL to open the Google Maps app from a custom route accessed via python API?
I am creating a Flask webapp that involves the use of the google maps API. I currently have JS query the flask backend for navigation results, using the googlemaps python library reference to compute a route calculation between two points. I have set alternatives=True to get multiple routes, and am now wondering how to use these route objects to create a custom google maps URL that will open The google maps app with the selected route.
All the solutions I have seen use maps URLs here that look something like: https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&parameters for a directions request but this seems to send a new directions calculation request to google and navigates to the maps app with that new directions request, which is not what I want. I want it to open google maps in navigation mode for the route I have already requested from google and clicked on in my app. I know navigation links can be achieved through dir_action=navigate but I want the link to work with the route I have clicked on in my app.
This seems like it should be possible, when using google maps normally, I can request a route in real time, click on one of the route alternatives, and create a link for that specific route and send it somewhere else like this, obviously the links are time sensitive but this sort of thing seems to be possible already. I wonder if I am going about this problem the wrong way, and if I should be using different frameworks entirely, but these have worked well for me for this project so far so I would like to continue to use them if possible
I use the decode_polyline function from the googlemaps api to send the polyline lat and long for the route to the front end, and then have added a listener that displays route data in a modal when the polyline is clicked on.
Here is the relevant JS
async function requestRoutes(start, end, waypoints = []) {
    try {
        const response = await fetch('/compute-route', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ start, end, waypoints })
        });

        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error('Failed to fetch route data');
        }
        const routeData = await response.json();
        if (routeData.error) {
            console.error('Error from server:', routeData.error);
            alert('Error calculating route. Please check input.');
        } else {
            //console.log('Route data:', routeData);
            curRouteData.push(routeData);
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error:', error);
        alert('An error occurred while fetching the route.');
    }
}

function displayRoutesOnMap(routeData) {
    //console.log(routeData)
    curRouteData[0].forEach((route, index) => {

        const polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
            path: route.overview_polyline,  
            strokeColor: index === 0 ? '#00FF00' : index===1 ? '#0000FF' :'#FF0000',  
            strokeOpacity: 0.7,
            strokeWeight: 4,
            map: map  
        });
        polyline.addListener('click', () => {
            showRouteInfo(route);
        });
        
        

    });
}

function showRouteInfo(route) {
    const routeDetails = document.getElementById('routeDetails');
    //console.log(route)
    routeDetails.innerHTML = '';
    route.legs.forEach(leg => {
        routeDetails.innerHTML += `${leg.start_address} to ${leg.end_address} : ${leg.steps.length} steps.`
      // more route details added
    });
    const mapsLink = document.getElementById("googleMapsButton")
    mapsLink.href = null; // I want help here if possible

    const routeModal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById('routeModal'));
    routeModal.show();
}

And here is the python that corresponds to the compute-route route:
@app.route('/compute-route', methods=['POST'])
def compute_route():
    data = request.get_json()
    start = data.get('start')
    end = data.get('end')
    directions_result = gmaps.directions(start, end, mode='driving', alternatives=True)

    for item in directions_result:
        item['overview_polyline'] = convert.decode_polyline(item['overview_polyline']['points'])
    
    return directions_result

All of my code works as I expect it to, the route is properly calculated and shown on the map from the polyline, and each listener for the polylines allow me to see the info for the route clicked on, now I just don't know how to create a maps link that doesn't just completely resend the navigation request to Google.
I see an old solution that uses a DirectionsRenderer Object here, and I have tried that, but I cannot get the DirectionsRenderer object to display routes from the python API backend responses, I am only having luck manually displaying the polyline. I get error InvalidValueError: setDirections: in property routes: not an Array when I instantiate a DirectionsRenderer object and pass my routeData object to it (the exact two lines of code I am adding in the displayRoutesOnMap function that error are:
const dRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
        draggable: true,
        map: map,
    });
dRenderer.setDirections(curRouteData[0])

